# Automatically append some text to every log message

Tags: python, logging

An application I'm working on uses the logging module to log errors etc. In such a case it would be nice to be able to include the HTTP referer, GET/POST arguments etc. in the log entry.

While it would be possible to append it to the message before calling `.error()` etc, I'm looking for a way to do it at a central location (without wrapping those functions of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now solved it using a custom formatter:

```
class IndicoMailFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        s = super(IndicoMailFormatter, self).format(record)
        return s + self._getRequestInfo()

    def _getRequestInfo(self):
        info = ['Additional information:']
        # ...
        return '\n\n%s' % '\n'.join(info)
```

This formatter can be easily set using the `class` option in logging.conf (or via python code).

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it, but I think that you can do it by specifying a `FORMAT` with `logging.basicConfig`.

From the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) documentation:

> ```
> FORMAT = "%(asctime)-15s %(clientip)s %(user)-8s %(message)s"
> logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
> d = {'clientip': '192.168.0.1', 'user': 'fbloggs'}
> logging.warning("Protocol problem: %s", "connection reset", extra=d)
> ```
>
> would print something like:
>
> 2006-02-08 22:20:02,165 192.168.0.1 fbloggs  Protocol problem: connection reset

Comment: I'd prefer a solution that does not require passing any additional options to the `warning()` call.

Comment: mmm ... if you don't want to pass additional arguments, then I'm afraid you have to write a wrapper.

Comment: Actually, I got it working by subclassing the `logging.Formatter` class.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best solution for you, if you don't want to add parameters when calling methods.